# Can someone tell me if it's possible to do a communication between a C# desktop application and a flutter desktop application?

Tags: c#, flutter, dart

I have a C# program, and I recently started learning about Flutter. I would like to know if there's a way for them to communicate and send strings to each other as parameters.

I don't even know how to start.
And I need do this without internet connection.

Comment: Check out "named pipes". You can run them on localhost between two processes. Also, network communication via TCP/HTTP/whateverProtocol is possible...

Comment: Today there is always the local loopback. So you don't need internet to do local networking. That means you can do the whole barrage of low level protocols but also message queues etc.

Comment: This is far too broad and opinion based for SO... but fortunately we already have similar somewhat recent (2008, when site was still deciding if list/recommendation questions were on-topic) and equally non-focused question on the same topic of IPC - so voted to close as duplicate instead of "too broad". Hopefully knowing the term (IPC - inter-process communication) would let you either make your own decision or narrow down the question.